# NO URL IS SET - error in jqGrid (Add, Delete dialog)

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I've following Grid to display data, now when I want to add new record it gives the error 'NO URL IS SET'

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PRGrid').jqGrid({
            //url from wich data should be requested
            url: '@Url.Action("BindData")?FillType=' + getFillType(),
            //event for inline edit
            onSelectRow: function (currentSelectedRow) {
                if (currentSelectedRow && currentSelectedRow != $.lastSelectedRow) {
                    //save changes in row 
                    $('#PRGrid').jqGrid('saveRow', $.lastSelectedRow, false);
                    $.lastSelectedRow = currentSelectedRow;
                }
                //trigger inline edit for row
            },
            //type of data
            datatype: 'json',
            //url access method type
            mtype: 'POST',
            //columns names
            colNames: ['Code', 'Name', 'No_Rooms', 'Dept_Code', 'Total_Items'],
            //columns model
            colModel: [
                        {   name: 'Code', index: 'Code', align: 'left', width: '120px', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { maxlength: 25, dataUrl: '@Url.Action("GetRooms")',
                            dataEvents: [{ 
                                type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
                                var ret = $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("selectRoom")?id=' + $(this).val(),
                                async: false,
                                success: function (ret) {
                                    $('#Name').val(ret.Name);
                                    $('#No_Rooms').val(ret.qty);
                                    $('#Dept_Code').val(ret.DeptCode);
                                    $('#Total_Items').val(ret.Total_Items);}
                                });}
                            }]
                        }},
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', align: 'left', formatter: "text", width: '185px', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly'} },
                        { name: 'No_Rooms', index: 'No_Rooms', align: 'left', formatter: "text", width: '102px', integer: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly'} },
                        { name: 'Dept_Code', index: 'Dept_Code', align: 'left', formatter: "text", width: '78px', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly'} },
                        { name: 'Total_Items', index: 'Total_Items', align: 'left', formatter: "text", width: '82px', integer: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { readonly: 'readonly'} },
                    ],
            //pager for grid            
            pager: $('#PRGridPager'),
            //number of rows per page
            rowNum: 5,
            //initial sorting column
            sortname: 'Code',
            //initial sorting direction
            sortorder: 'asc',
            recreateForm:true,
            //we want to display total records count
            viewrecords: true,
            //grid height
            height: '100%'
        });

        $('#PRGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#PRGridPager',
                { add: true, del: true, edit:false, search: true },
                {width: '330', url:'@Url.Action("InsertPRGridRecord")', closeAfterAdd: true },
                {width: '330', url:'@Url.Action("DeleteGridRecord")'});

        var dialogPosition = $(this).offset();
```

Problem arrise when I want to add or delete the record from the grid,

Here I've defined both the methods InsertPRGridRecord() and DeleteGridRecord(), but it gives the same error 'NO URL IS SET' at the time of submitting the data on Add Record or Delete Record dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem exist because you use incorrect the parameters of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). Your current code uses `'@Url.Action("DeleteGridRecord")'` as URL of "Add" and `'@Url.Action("InsertPRGridRecord")'` as URL of "Edit". The URL of "Delete" is not specified.

Comment: @ITppl: You are welcome! Such thing like this are simple if another person look on your code, but it can take many time to find the reason if one search for the reason along. :-)